# Hibernate spring tomcat - how to debug the database connection

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I am playing around with this tutorial and it's running okay on my Tomcat7 server: http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-mvc-4-rest-angularjs-hibernate-4-integration-crud-tutorial-with-ngresource-example

The 'only' problem is that it doesn't seem to connect to the database properly. The app is meant to fetch the data from a table at start-up, but this does not happen. I have scanned the catalina.out and localhost.out logs for error but found nothing.

My issue is that the hibernate framework abstracts so much of the actual mechanics of the database connection and querying that I don't even know where to start debugging this.

The question is: where to look for logs? Alternativey, where in my code should I add some debug-logs (e.g. using Log4j)? I've inserted some code snippets from my app below.

Thanks for any help.

AHL

checked that mysql runs on port 3306:

```
vagrant@precise32:/var/log$ netstat -tln                                        Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44446           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::36003                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::46532                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN
vagrant@precise32:/var/log$
```

my database configuration class:

```
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/concretepage");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");
    return dataSource;
}
```

the database and table exists:

```
mysql> use concretepage;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select * from person;
+-----+--------+----------+
| pid | name   | location |
+-----+--------+----------+
|   1 | Mahesh | Varanasi |
|   2 | Ram    | Ayodhya  |
+-----+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: You should find the logs in your tomcat home Directory under logs

Comment: Why use logs to debug? Why not use a debugger?

Comment: Use Slf4J / Logback to log to the server Console

Comment: Did you try adding  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> to your configuration?

Comment: did you solve it?